# List SOME members (which are ADGroups) of the "master" ADGroup

Tags: powershell

I have a "Parent" ADGroup (`ADParent`) which has multiple ADGroups as members (`ADChild1`, `ADChild2`).

I would like to list all ADChilds for the ADParent but filter keep only the ADChild with name containing "1"

This will list ALL members:

```
Get-AdGroupMember ADParent | select Name
```

This does not work:

```
Get-AdGroupMember ADParent | select Name | -Filter Name -like "1"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to filter a stream of output from another cmdlet:

```
Get-ADGroupMember ADParent |Where-Object Name -like '*1*' |Select Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative querying AD for groups where their `MemberOf` property contains the parent group:

```
$parentDN = (Get-ADGroup ParentGroup).DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(Name=*1*)(MemberOf=$parentDN))" | Select-Object Name
```